# Cannot Unify two hypotheses which are identical

Tags: coq, coqide

I have two hypotheses in context, but when I try to `apply` one to another, I get the error `unable to unify`. I should be able to unify them. The two hypotheses are as follo

`IHl : forallb func l = true -> All (fun x : X => func x = true) l
 H1 : All (fun x : X => func x = true) l`

My goal is to get the premise from IHl by applying IHl to H1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common confusion among beginners.  When used on a hypothesis, the `apply` tactic works as follows: if `H1 : A -> B` and `H2 : A`, `apply H1 in H2` replaces `H2` by `H2 : B`.  Thus, for your proof to succeed, you would have to have the reverse implication `IHl : All ... l -> forallb func l = true` in the context, or the hypothesis `H1 : forallb func l = true`.

Comment: But shouldn't I be able to use it in reverse, as described in the proof method "Backwards Reasoning" in the chapter "Tactics" in "Logical Foundations"?

Comment: Backwards reasoning works when applying to the *goal*. If your goal says `All ... l`, then you can write `apply IHl` and reduce it to proving `forallb func l = true`.